# NSMutableArray and removeobjectsatindex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *changeme =[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];

        //[changeme addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];

        for (int i=2; i<=100;i+=2)
        {
                [changeme addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

        }

        for(int x=0;x<[changeme count];x++)
        {

            NSLog(@"Item here is %i",[[changeme objectAtIndex:x]intValue]);
        }

        [changeme removeObjectAtIndex:2];
    return 0;
}

}
```

**removeObjectAtIndex** remove the object at the index.My program should print all the even numbers from 2-100. So,`index[2]=6` should be delete. But,It's not reacting like, it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup its delete object at 2. When u print ur array then u r not able to see object which index is 2.

```
for(int x=0;x<[changeme count];x++)
        {

            NSLog(@"Item here is %i",[[changeme objectAtIndex:x]intValue]);
        }

        [changeme removeObjectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"%@",[changeme description]);
```

6 is no more in array.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are removing the object only after the items are printed.

If you move the code

```
    [changeme removeObjectAtIndex:2];
```

to start of the second `for` loop, then you would see that index[2] = 6, got deleted.

So it should be as follows:

```
    for (int i=2; i<=100;i+=2)
    {
            [changeme addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }

    [changeme removeObjectAtIndex:2];

    for(int x=0;x<[changeme count];x++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Item here is %i",[[changeme objectAtIndex:x]intValue]);
    }
```